# Upgrade from 3-Months to a Year of Playstation Plus

Tags: playstation-plus

If I purchase the year of Plus whilst my 3-month is still active will it automatically start the year once the 3-months has expired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the PS+ time you buy is cumulative. This means that you basically have a buffer of 3 months time left. When you add 12 months, you'll have 15 months left.

So once your first 3 months expire, you'll still have 12 months in your account, which will be used automatically.